# True or False: If f is analytic and maps the deleted unit disk to the unit disk, then 0 is not a pole for f.

Tags: complex-analysis

I am studying for my final exam in complex variables and I ran across this true or false question.

True or False: If $f:D(0;1)\setminus\{0\} \rightarrow D(0;1)$ is analytic, then $0$ is not a pole for $f$.

I think it's true. If $0$ was a pole for $f$, then $|f(z)|$ would explode near $0$. So its range would be unbounded... right?

Does any one know where I can find more concept questions like this so that I can find more holes in my understanding.

Comment: $f$ is analytic *on which domain*?

Comment: "If f:D(0;1)\{0} --> D(0;1) is analytic, then 0 is not a pole for f." This is how the question was originally, but I don't know how to use Latex yet and I thought it looked tacky. I'm sorry.

Comment: You may want to see [this](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference), for the future.

Comment: It seems that $f$ is bounded in a neighborhood of the singularity, so it is removable by the removable singularity theorem. (If the singularity were a pole, it would be unbounded.)

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Removable_singularity#Riemann.27s_theorem